# removing elements from a list

Tags: python

How can i remove elements with a value of 0 as they pop upp in this loop?

```
y = [4, 2, 7, 9]
x = input("run?")
while x:
    for i in range(len(y)):
        y[i] -= 1
    y.append(len(y))
    print(y)
```

Comment: `while x` will put you into an infinite loop if `x` evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 2):

you could always use a list comprehension to filter them:

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] -= 1
y = [x for x in y if x != 0]  # <-- added here
y.append(len(y))
```

**EDIT**:

I'm silly - these operations could even be combined as so:

```
while whatever: #<-- fix as suggested by comment on your question
    y = [z-1 for z in y if z > 1]
    y.append(len(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y = filter(lambda i: i != 0, y)
```

Comment: note - filter+lambda is often said to be slower than a list comprehension; you might be interested in [this related answer by Alex Martelli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map).