# Remove element in list using list comprehension - Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list like this:

```
['A','B','C']
```

What I need is to remove one element based on the input I got in the function. For example, if I decide to remove A it should return:

```
['B','C']
```

I tried with no success

```
list = ['A','B','C']
[var for var in list if list[var] != 'A']
```

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016304/removing-elements-from-a-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915920/how-to-delete-an-item-in-a-list-if-it-exists-python/4915964#4915964

Comment: No-one has actually pointed out your true mistake here: In the list comprehension, it will try to evaluate list['A'] which wont work for two reasons. 1) it's not a dict and 2) you're trying to use the value as the index

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simple `lst.remove('A')` will work:

```
>>> lst = ['A','B','C']
>>> lst.remove('A')
['B', 'C']
```

However, one call to `.remove` only removes the *first* occurrence of `'A'` in a list. To remove all `'A'` values you can use a loop:

```
for x in range(lst.count('A')):
    lst.remove('A')
```

If you insist on using list comprehension you can use

```
>>> [x for x in lst if x != 'A']
['B', 'C']
```

The above will remove *all* elements equal to `'A'`.

Comment: In my particular use case of very long lists, a list comprehension is blazingly faster than the lst.remove approach. So, I insist on using it!

Comment: Additionally the list comprehension allows to add conditional removal easily (remove if condition is true). great solution

Answer (score 13):

The improvement to your code (which is almost correct) would be:

```
list = ['A','B','C']
[var for var in list if var != 'A']
```

However, @frostnational's approach is *better* for single values.

If you are going to have a list of values to disallow, you can do that as:

```
list = ['A','B','C', 'D']
not_allowed = ['A', 'B']
[var for var in list if var not in not_allowed]
```

Comment: Thank you, I think for better coding purposes I will accept the other answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you not sure whether the element exists or not, you might want to check before you delete:

```
if 'A' in lst:
    lst.remove('A')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
originalList=['A','B','C']
print([val for val in originalList if val!='A'])
```

This prints

```
['B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `remove` method of list. Just do `list.remove('A')` and it will be removed.

If you have the index of the item to be removed, use the `pop` method. `list.pop(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Find this simplified code:

```
list1 = [12,24,35,24,88,120,155]

while 24 in list1:

    list1.remove(24)

print(list1)
```

Best Luck!

Comment: This is not a list comprehension, which is what the OP is explicitly asking for. -1

Answer (score 0):

You were really close:

```
list = ['A','B','C']
[var for var in list if list[list.index(var)] != 'A']
```

You tried to refer to a list item using a syntax that calls for an index value.